# Templated operator() method of lambda object defined inside method of templated class does not evaluate if constexpr statement

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have a templated class called `sys`, out of whose parameters there is a non-type `uint64_t` parameter (let's call it `freq`).

My `sys` class stores many objects of type `bod` - the `bod` class is also templated and accepts a `uint64_t` non-type template parameter that is also called `freq`.

The `bod` class has a specialization for the special case where `freq == 0`. In that case, the method `method_A` is NOT defined (but **is** for any non-zero `freq` (`freq > 0`)).

In one method in my `sys` class, I create a lambda that has a templated `operator()` method (note: **not** a templated lambda itself, i.e., where the anonymous `ClosureType` class would be templated; here only the `operator()` method is templated, using `[]<>(){}` syntax).

The lambda is templated with 3 boolean (non-type) template parameters - the first one being `M`. The lambda captures `this` and does not accept any parameters.

Within the lambda, I loop through all the `bod` objects stored in my `sys` instance. I use, within the loop, an `if constexpr (M && freq)` statement to only call `method_A` on a `bod` object when `M == true` (`M` being the boolean template parameter that the lambda's `operator()` method is templated with) and when `freq > 0` (`freq` being the `sys` class's `uint64_t` template parameter), since `method_A` would  not be defined if `freq == 0` (and I also only would want to call `method_A` if `M == true` for other reasons).

My question then is, why does the compiler give the error `"no member named 'method_A' in 'bod<int, int, int, 0>'"` (the `int`s being the the types the other template parameters were instantiated with)?

I ask because I am guarding against precisely that by including the `if constexpr` statement, to ensure that `method_A` is defined for the `bod` objects.

I am sure there is something going on with the order of template instantiations that I am missing here. Perhaps it has something to do with the `operator()` method of the lambda being templated, instead of the anonymous `ClosureType` itself? If so, is it because the anonymous `ClosureType` class is instantiated before the template instantation of its `operator()` method, making the compiler reach the call to `method_A` before it knows that it would never occur since it's guarded by the `if constexpr` statement?

To make the issue clearer, I provide a barebones implementation of the problem:

```cpp
// primary template for "bod" class
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, uint64_t freq>
class bod {
    // instance variables
    // methods
    void method_A () {
        // funky stuff
    }
};

// template specialization for the case of freq == 0
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class bod<A, B, C, 0> {
    // instance variables
    // methods
    // NO method_A DEFINED WITHIN THE SPECIALIZATION
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C, uint64_t freq>
class sys {
    std::list<bod<A, B, C, freq>> list;
    void problem_func() {
        static auto lam = [this]<bool M, bool Y, bool Z>{
            for (bod<A, B, C, freq>& b : list) {
                // do stuff with b
                if constexpr (M && freq) {
                    b.method_A(); // "no member named 'method_A'" error, even though...
                } // ... the if constexpr block guarantees it to be defined
            }
        };
        // use lam<> with combinations of true/false as the boolean template parameters
    }
};
```

As I said, I'm almost certain it's got something to do with the `ClosureType` vs the `operator()` method being templated, but I'd love to hear from someone who can shed some light on it. Cheers.

Comment: Your example does not seem to cause the compilation error: <https://godbolt.org/z/zKf167avn>. But based on your problem, it could be that `freq` isn't a dependent value (maybe some global variable), so the type of `b` isn't dependent, so `b.method_A()` is always compiled. It could be something else, try to make an example that doesn't compile (or tell us your compiler if it isn't compiling for you). And btw, the closure type is "templated" (it's in a template), even though it's not a template itself.

Comment: @Artyer Thanks! And yes, I should have mentioned, I'm on GCC (g++) version 14.0.0 (Apple clang).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reduced your example to a much simpler case, and now it looks like a clang bug.

```
template <bool freq> struct bod { void method_A () {} };
template <>          struct bod<false> {};

template <bool freq>
void problem_func() {
    auto lam = []<bool M>(){
        bod<freq> b;
        if constexpr (M && freq) {
            b.method_A();
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    problem_func<false>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9vYvv8v3x

What's interesting is that if you remove the `(M && freq)` condition, and put in a *less constrained* condition of just `(freq)`, then it compiles.

So somehow, the dependency on the function template parameter causes clang to evaluate the body anyway, possibly because it takes a different path through handling it, since "freq" is known from the outside, but M is a dependent type.  (When it only depends on freq, by the time it gets to the *if constexpr* it already knows that the condition is false.  Clang seems to not realize that false and (dependent value X) is still always false, even if it doesn't know about X.)

Therefore, it seems to work if you change the layout of your code to utilize this insight:

Putting an outer `if constexpr` on freq, and *then* another if constexpr (M), the compiler is able to make the body "go away" when freq is 0, regardless of what M is.

```
if constexpr (freq) {
    if constexpr (M) {
        b.method_A();
    }
}
```

Next problem, your lambda is hard to use since a user has to provide template parameters that are not deduced from the arguments.  Maybe this is due to you making an example, but to demonstrate invoking the inner lambda the easiest way I found was to add an extra parameter so that the bool argument M could be deduced from a std::bool_constant.

This compiles and runs as I would expect, even on clang:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int freq> struct bod { 
    void method_A () { std::cout << "methodA called\n";} 
};
template <> struct bod<false> {};

template <int freq>
void problem_func() {
    auto lam = []<bool M>(std::bool_constant<M> arg){
        bod<freq> b;
        if constexpr (freq != 0) {
            if constexpr (M) {
                b.method_A();
            }
        }
    };

    std::cout << "lam called with true_type\n";
    lam(std::true_type{});
    std::cout << "lam called with false_type\n";
    lam(std::false_type{}); 
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "freq=0:\n";
    problem_func<0>();
    std::cout << "freq=1:\n";
    problem_func<1>();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
freq=0:
lam called with true_type
lam called with false_type
freq=1:
lam called with true_type
methodA called
lam called with false_type
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bv8P4dWhT

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, much appreciated. Indeed, your suggestion for nesting the `if constexpr (M)` is smart. In the end I ended up just making it a separate private templated method.